# Sync Laravel Production Code using Git

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-5

Currently my local code and production code follow the same directory structure. After, `push`ing my changes from local, i `pull` it on the server and it works fine.

Website path is something like `http://abcde.com/code/laravel/public`

`code` directory is under version-control

Now, i'm trying to change path to `http://abcde.com`

i followed [this guide](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e) and thinking about moving source code out of server directory. So, the structure:

```
/var/www will contain content of laravel's public folder
/var/source will contain laravel
```

But then how'll i manage it with Git because the structure will be different?

**Edit**: I'm aware of two solutions:

1. Changing apache root
2. use .htaccess to remove public

For 1, there is a possibility that we'll add another directory `admin` in `www`, which will have its own source code. So, existing content of `www` will be moved to a sub-directory.

For 2, It's not recommended to keep source code inside web server root.

Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: why not store your git directory root at `/var/www`, and point apache's root to `/var/www/public`?

Comment: Is there any other way around? Because there is a possibility that we'll add another directory `admin` in `www` which will have its own source code. So, existing content of  `www` will be moved to a sub-directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thought is, you can make symlinks to preserve your directory structure, with this you help apache to keep it original configuration, and at the same time will no have any issues with version control.

Symlink is by using this command: `ln -s /path/to/origin path/to/destination`.

Bests ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler procedure. Pull you complete project in `var/www` and add a `.htaccess` in `var/www` which contains -

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Now you will be able to use `http://abcde.com`

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: "Please note that this isn't the recommended way." This is the only thing it says against `.htaccess`. Well if you want to use your own procedure then change your local structure as well and push it and then pull it.

Comment: Thanks Risul. I've updated my question so it might make more sense now.